# Google docs a veces devuelve página en blanco (about:blank)

Tags: java, jsp, aplicación-web, google-api, google-documentos

La url https://docs.google.com/gview?url= a veces devuelve una página en blanco. És aleatorio y cuando pasa tienes que actualizar hasta que vuelve a mostrar el documento pertinente (por suerte falla pocas veces). Pasa tanto poniendo la url directamente en el navegador o llamándola des de .jsp con "response.sendRedirect(URL)" que es mi caso.
¿Alguna solución o alquien sabe los motivos?
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El autor de [la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40425780/1595451) a [Google Docs viewer returning 204 responses, no longer working, alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40414039/1595451)
 comparte un "hack" / truco que consiste en refrescar el ifram cada 2 segundos hasta que se Google Doc Viewer cargue correctamente. El código compartido por el autor de la respuesta, implica el uso de jQuery, es el siguiente:

```html
<style>
  .holds-the-iframe {
    background: url(/img/loading.gif) center center no-repeat;
  }
</style>

<div class="holds-the-iframe">
  <iframe id="iframeID" name="iframeID" src="https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=www.example.com&embedded=true"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
  function reloadIFrame() {
    document.getElementById("ifm").src = document.getElementById("iframeID").src;
  }

  timerId = setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 2000);

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#iframeID').on('load', function() {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      console.log("Finally Loaded");
    });
  });
</script>
```